# Listen to click events inside CKEditor dialog

Tags: javascript, dialog, ckeditor

I have a ckeditor instance, to which I added a custom dialog box using:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('quicklinkDialog', function(editor) {
   return {
     title: 'Quick Links',
     minWidth: 400,
     minHeight: 200,

     contents: [
       {
        id: 'tab1',
        label: 'Add a quick link',
        elements: [
        {
         type: 'html',
         html: '<p>This is some text and then: <a href="">Click me!</a></p>'
        }]
   };
 });
```

I want to add a "click" event listener on the link inside my dialog box. When that link is clicked, content will be inserted into my textrea (the dialog box will also be closed).

Anyone knows how I might do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

```
{
    type: 'html',
    html: '<p>This is some text and then: <a href="">Click me!</a></p>',
    onLoad: function( a ) {
        CKEDITOR.document.getById( this.domId ).on( 'click', function() {
            var dialog = this.getDialog();
            dialog.hide();
            dialog._.editor.insertHtml( this.html );
        }, this );
    }
}
```

See the [API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition) to know more.